# Building a MySQL view with union of selects

Tags: mysql, select, view, union

I have a table with the following structure: 
the columns names are metrics (MT_NAME, MT_ADDRESS, MT_PHONE etc) and the rows are the values/scores of the metrics from that ocurrence (0, 6, 8, 9, 10).
Like this:

```
+---------+------------+----------+
| MT_NAME | MT_ADDRESS | MT_PHONE |
+---------+------------+----------+
|       0 |          9 |        6 |
|       6 |         10 |        0 |
|       8 |         10 |        0 |
+---------+------------+----------+
```

I want to build a view with 3 columns: one with the names of the table's columns, one with the distinct values from that column and one with the frequency which those values appeared in that column.
Something like this:

```
+------------+----------+-------+
|   LEGEND   | CATEGORY | VALUE |
+------------+----------+-------+
| MT_NAME    |     0    |     1 |
| MT_NAME    |     6    |     1 |
| MT_NAME    |     8    |     1 |
| MT_ADDRESS |     9    |     1 |
| MT_ADDRESS |     10   |     2 |
| MT_PHONE   |     0    |     2 |
| MT_PHONE   |     6    |     1 |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select 'MT_NAME' as legend, mt_name as category, count(*) as frequency
from t
group by mt_name
union all
select 'MT_ADDRESS' as legend, mt_address as category, count(*) as frequency
from t
group by mt_name
union all
select 'MT_PHONE' as legend, mt_phone as category, count(*) as frequency
from t
group by mt_name;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!